# My program is not working, it is not copying the content

Tags: c, file-handling

There are three header files accompanying this assignment which are copied versions of `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h` and `string.h`.

My program should identify which of these header files are included in the program and replace the `#include` statement with the corresponding file (content of file).
I end up getting an empty output file. Nothing is copied to the output file.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 5000
    
void header_exchange(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check for the input arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("%d\n",argc);
        //printf("Must have an input file name in the arguments\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    header_exchange(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}

void header_exchange(char *fin)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    FILE *h1;
    FILE *h2;
    FILE *h3;
    char buff1[MAX];
    char buff2[MAX];
    char buff3[MAX];
    char buff4[MAX];
    fp1 = fopen(fin, "r"); 
    fp2 = fopen("out.c", "w");
    h1 = fopen("pa1_stdio.h", "r");
    h2 = fopen("pa1_stlib.h", "r");
    h3 = fopen("pa1_string.h", "r");
    
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(buff1, sizeof(buff1), fp1) != NULL)
    {
        if (buff1[0] == '#')
        {
            if (strstr(buff1, "stdio") != 0)
            {
                while (fgets(buff2, sizeof(buff2), h1))
                {
                    fputs(buff2, fp2);
                }               
            }
            
            if (strstr(buff1, "stdlib") != 0)
            {
                while (fgets(buff2, sizeof(buff2), h2))
                {
                    fputs(buff2, fp2);
                }
            }
            
            if (strstr(buff1, "string") != 0)
            {
                while (fgets(buff2, sizeof(buff2), h3))
                {
                    fputs(buff2, fp2);
                }
            }   
        }

        fputs(buff1,fp2);
    }    

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(h1);
    fclose(h2);
    fclose(h3);
}
```

**in.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid Arguments\n");
    }

    return 0;
```

Comment: "My program is not working" lacks details.  What are the arguments to `main()`?  What did you see, what was expected?  Best to post a [mcve].

Comment: @chux-reinstate-monica: There is only one argument passed which is the filename "in.c"

Comment: Also verify `fp1 != NULL`, `h1 != NULL`,  `h2 != NULL`,  `h3 != NULL`.   `char buff3[MAX]; char buff4[MAX];` unused.  Suggest simplifying and remove them.

Comment: When your input line is (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>` you want to copy the contents of the file `pa1_stdio.h` to the output. Your code does that, but it _also_ copies the original `#include` command after the file body. Near the bottom of the loop, change `fputs(buff1,fp2);` into `else fputs(buff1,fp2);`

Comment: Or, when copying, you could just replace `#include <stdio.h>` with `#include "pa1_stdio.h"` instead of copying out the contents of the file.

Comment: Copy the content of the files

Comment: So, fix with the `else` as I mentioned. Also, note that you may have a typo. For `stdlib.h`, you are copying `pa1_stlib.h` and _not_ `pa1_stdlib.h`. If your file is _truly_ `pa1_stlib.h`, then that is fine. Otherwise, if the file _should_ be `pa1_stdlib.h`, your code generates a segfault because `h2` will be `NULL`

Comment: “Scrapped” means thrown away like rubbish. Is that’s what’s happened to these header files, or have you “copied” them?

Comment: I have copied from the header file and renamed it.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear but here few points

1.
if i understand correctly you want to replace the #include xxxxxx.h with the corresponding pa_xxxxxx.h content
but then you read to buff1 MAX size of bytes (you could use[getline() see here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) )
then you copy the entire my_xxxxxx.h file and you copy buff1 again - but you didnt remove the original #include that you wanted to remove

2.
the second and third `if` statements , it is not clear from the problem description if it need to be `else if` or is `if` enough

Comment: I think my question was clear.                                                                                                               1. Yes you got it right.  I am trying not  to copy the # statement, but instead copy the content of header file.                                                                                                                         2. You do understand the problem as per your reflection in 1.

Comment: so what you actually say that all what is not working for you is the fact that you copied buff1 without removinf the #include xxxxxx.h , this is rather simple as the size of #include xxxxx.h is known (15 or 16 bytes depending if you are in first , second or third header , then when you do `fputs(buff1,fp2)` just do it with offset

Comment: Can you give me an example as to how should i use offset in order to get me started with it...?